# C# upload file to Ruby on Rails application

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails

I assume this is possible, its just a matter of implementation detail. How do I go about making a C# program upload a file to a Ruby on Rails controller already set to accept uploads? Which headers do I need to set in C# and how do I go about passing the XSS protection mechanisms Rails puts in place?

This would be a public program, so I'd obviously do some file validation and checking on the Rails side, but it should still be somewhat secure.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use something that consumes restful api's such as

[restsharp](http://restsharp.org/)
or 
[restagent](http://restagent.codeplex.com/)
since rails is a restful framework